# Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls alternative NuGet package

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url, nuget

This NuGet package FriendlyUrls only supports C# Web App. But, I am now building a VB Web App and that package does not work for my case. So, are there similar packages that they support VB Web App and have the same behavior as FriendlyUrls?

In Identity Server 4, I have a configuration for the request from clients as shown below. And please notice that the AllowedRedirectUris is "http://test.mydomain:5001/signincallback" because the Identity Server 4 is built based on the MVC model.

```
{
  "ClientId": "test.mydomain.com",
  "ClientName": "My Client App",
  "AllowedRedirectUris": [
    "http://test.mydomain:5001/signincallback"
  ],
  "SubjectId": "anonymous",
  "RequestedScopes": "",
  "Raw": {
    "client_id": "test.mydomain.com",
    "response_type": "code id_token",
    "scope": "openid profile",
    "redirect_uri": "http://test.mydomain:5001/signincallback",
    "state": "873a0bbf6755485cafb112e74f3a81b8",
    "nonce": "783e367fb17b42948211af2cfa68fbbb",
    "acr_values": "tenant:e443e8f8-74f7-42b2-9304-b247cf560f79",
    "response_mode": "form_post"
  }
}
```

And in my client app (VB Webform App - It is not MVC), I create a request to match the format above:

```
Private ReadOnly _authority As String
    Private ReadOnly _clientId As String
    Private ReadOnly _tenantId As String

    Protected Sub New()
        _authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("auth:authority")
        _clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("auth:clientId")
        _tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("auth:tenantId")
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim hostUrl = $"{Me.Request.Url.Scheme}://{Me.Request.Url.Authority}"
        Dim hostUri = New Uri(hostUrl, UriKind.Absolute)
        Dim redirectUri = New Uri(hostUri, "signincallback").ToString()
        Dim client = New HttpClient()
        Dim disco = client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(_authority).Result
        Dim state = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")
        Dim nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")
        SetTempCookie(state, nonce)
        Dim authorizeUrl = New RequestUrl(disco.AuthorizeEndpoint).CreateAuthorizeUrl(clientId:=_clientId, responseType:=OidcConstants.ResponseTypes.CodeIdToken, scope:="openid profile", redirectUri:=redirectUri, state:=state, nonce:=nonce, acrValues:=$"tenant:{_tenantId}", responseMode:=OidcConstants.ResponseModes.FormPost)
        Response.Redirect(authorizeUrl)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SetTempCookie(ByVal state As String, ByVal nonce As String)
        Dim tempId = New ClaimsIdentity(AuthenticationTypes.TemporaryCookieAuthentication)
        tempId.AddClaim(New Claim("state", state))
        tempId.AddClaim(New Claim("nonce", nonce))
        Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(tempId)
    End Sub
```

And the result is that my client app can load the Identity Server 4 login page. After I log in to the page, it cannot load to the "signincallback.aspx" page.

The root cause here is, my client app is VB Webform and it is not MVC. So, the AlloweredRedirectUris above will reload the URL "http://test.mydomain:5001/signincallback" and it does not understand what it is.
If I enter the URL http://test.mydomain:5001/signincallback.aspx, it is able to load the page.

I tried to use the NuGet FriendyUrls to enables automatic resolution of extensionless URLs to ASP.NET file-based handlers (e.g. ASPX pages) to tell my client that the URL "http://test.mydomain:5001/signincallback" should be understood as "http://test.mydomain:5001/signincallback.aspx", but it does not work.

Comment: It *should* work with VB.NET, even if there is no documentation showing that language. In what way, exactly, does it seem to not work?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Thanks for your comment. Please see my update above.